# How to get the data for a specific date range in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a data set from the internet:

I am using the following code based on my local file which is JSON output:

```
Validdata = []
for new in Sampledata:
    print(str(new['title']) + " | " + str(new['published'][:10]))
    Validdata.append(new)
```

My output:

```
Amnesia: Collection Hits Xbox One Next Week | 2018-08-27
(USA) Building Safety Technician | 2018-08-27
SONY VAIO VPCCA15FG DRIVERS DOWNLOAD | 2018-08-26
Google Alert - windows 10 | 2018-08-27
```

If we see I have a data like this with dates at the end of each title, and I want to print out only the articles which falls between certain date range:

I tried using this to compare, but I am getting this error message:

```
Startdate = '2018-09-01'
Enddate = '2018-10-01'
underDaterange = []
for value in Sampledata['title']  and Sampledata['published'][:10] in range [Startdate:Enddate]:
       underDaterange.append(value)
```

Error Message:

```
 TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: `Sampledata` seems to be a list. Lists dont have keys like `title`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the built-in `datetime.strptime`

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = ('2018-01-01', '2018-08-27', '2018-09-01', '2018-10-01')
format = '%Y-%m-%d'
start_dt = datetime.strptime('2018-08-01', format)
end_dt = datetime.strptime('2018-09-30', format)

[date for date in dates if datetime.strptime(date, format) > start_dt and datetime.strptime(date, format) < end_dt]
# ['2018-08-27', '2018-09-01']
```

Also, please review your variable naming conventions and use of indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message stated that use are using string as a index in range function.

Create the date objects:

```
from datetime import date

start_date = date(2017, 1, 1)
end_date = date(2018, 10, 4)
```

use dates as int in range function:

```
range(int((end_date - start_date).days))
```